# Django & Jinja2 templates using {{ url() }}

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to figure out how to pass my user_id within my html using jinja's {{ url() }}, using urls that don't need any id like `/dashboard/` work fine but I need to pass an id to this- example: `/user/3` . I have tried the following with no success:

```
{{ url('detail') }}
{{ url('detail', user_id=User.id) }}
{{ url('detail', User.id) }}
```

Here's part of my views and html:

views.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', dashboard, name='dashboard'),          
    path('user/<int:user_id>/', detail, name='detail'),    
]
```

dashboard.html

```
{% for User in all_users %}

    {{ url('detail') }}

{% endfor %}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I've only used Jinja2 on small projects, so I can't help as much as I'd like. I believe you can accomplish the same for the current user in Django's default template rendered with `{% url 'detail' user.id %}`. Does using `user.id` work rather than iterating through `all_users`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was iterating through all users as i wanted to display all users and then href them to their own user page. Solution turns out to be {{ url('detail', args=[User.id] )}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
{% for User in all_users %}
    {{ url('detail', args=[User.id] )}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It seems that `url` is an alias for `reverse`. I needed to add some kwargs. I was able to pass kwargs using `{{ url('detail', kwargs={'slug': User.id}) }}` as explained in the docs for `reverse`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: Great workaround for an important use case -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 3.2+ there is [official backend support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) for Jinja2 - I'm guessing you were using [django-jinja](https://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/) which provides an implementation of the `url` function but it's fairly straightforward to integrate Django and Jinja now without additional dependencies (besides Jinja2 obviously).

First, configure settings file's `TEMPLATES` key and add a dictionary entry with the jinja2 backend:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'extensions': [<custom extensions if any>]
            'environment': 'yourapp.jinja2.environment',
            ...
         },
    },
    ...
]
```

The key part of this is the `environment` key which maps to the string `'yourapp.jinja2.environment'`, a function defined in `yourapp/jinja2.py` that returns a Jinja2 Environment object. You could name this anything you want, e.g., `core/jinja_environment.py` but the Django docs suggest `jinja2.py` so we'll stick with that.

```
# example yourapp/jinja2.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.templatetags.static import static

from jinja2 import Environment

def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': static,
        'url': reverse,
        'settings': settings,
        ...
    })
    return env
```

Here we can bind any Python function (including Django functions) to variable names that we want available in our Jinja2 environment. In this example, we can invoke `static(...)` within our Jinja templates and call off to the Django static function defined in `django.templatetags.static`. Similarly, `url` is bound to the Django [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/) function so `url('detail', args=[user.id])` should work. If you prefer a signature like `{{ url('detail', pk=123) }}` without generating an invalid arguments error you can define your own function:

```
def jinja_url(viewname, *args, **kwargs):
    return reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

and bind `'url': jinja_url` in `env.globals.update` instead.

It's also important to note that Django looks for your jinja templates in a `jinja2` directory under your app dir, not the `templates` directory.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
{% url 'detail' user.id %}
```

Then, in `views.py`, your corresponding function should receive `user_id` as an argument (internally `user.id` becomes `user_id`).